# GateIn - redirect within portlet

Tags: redirect, portlet, jboss-portal, gatein

How can you redirect a user by URL (within backing bean) to some other page within portlet? We are using **GateIn 3.1 on JBoss 5.1.0**

Usually, `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("url")` is enough, but here it doesn't work, it doesn't redirect user.

`context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, page)` doesn't work either.

We want to avoid making navigation rules for every possible page we can redirect to.

EDIT:
It appears `a4j:commandButton` was causing some problems, after we replaced it with `h:commandButton` we are being redirected but not only within portlet but within portal.

Comment: Did you try FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse().sendRedirect("url"); FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); ?

Comment: I don't have sendRedirect method. And i tried with responseComplete, but that causes something like portal redirect, because i get empty page with only "<?xml version="1.0"?>" on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other alternative (to having many navigation cases in `faces-config.xml`) I've found that works is using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setViewId(page)` to redirect, where page is `String page = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId()`.

Answer (score 0):

To have sendRedirect available, you have to cast object response to HttpServletResponse :

```
HttpServletResponse objHttpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)
                          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                      .getExternalContext()
                                      .getResponse();
objHttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(url);
```

This is doing a 302 redirect, managed by browser.

Comment: I know, but response is not HttpServletResponse object, it is org.jboss.portletbridge.richfaces.BufferedResourceResponseWrapper.